My Powershell function won't work and I don't know why
I am new to powershell scripting and wrote a script for filtering details of my CA Templates. I added function but it doesn't get called and I don't receive an error message. Ill show you some the code:
### PowerShell Script to Inventory Certificate Templates and Export to Excel

# Import necessary modules
Import-Module ImportExcel

# Function to parse the certutil -v -Template output
function Parse-CertTemplate {
    param (
        [string]$TemplateOutput
    )
    Write-Output "Function Call $TemplateOutput"
    $parsedTemplate = @{}

    # Function Code

    return $parsedTemplate
}



# Output file path
$outputFile = "C:\ADCS_Template_Inventory.xlsx"

# Collect all templates using certutil
$templateList = certutil -CATemplates
$templates = @()

# Extract template names from the output
$templateNames = $templateList | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match '^(\S+): (\S+)') {
        $Matches[1]
    }
}

# Loop through each template and collect detailed information
foreach ($templateName in $templateNames) {
    Write-Output "Loop $templateName"
    $templateOutput = certutil -v -Template $templateName | Out-String
    Write-Output "Loop $templateOutput"
    $templateData = Parse-CertTemplate -TemplateOutput $templateOutput
    $templates += $templateData
}

# Convert to Excel
$templates | Export-Excel -Path $outputFile -AutoSize -Title "ADCS Template Inventory"

Write-Output "Export completed. File saved to $outputFile"

So the debug output inside the function won't get triggered, but the one with templateOutput before the call does.
Any idea what I did wrong?

How do I write a good title?

Which debugger are you using to step through your program?

Im not using a debugger, I just let the script run through and look out for the outputs.

Please do yourself (and all of us at Stackoverflow) a favor and use a debugger. Visual Studio Code is free and works on multiple platforms. https://code.visualstudio.com/download

And $templateOutput is  really of type string with a length -gt 0?

You are doing something with the output of certutil -v -Template output, But you do not tell us how this template output looks like, so this is not a [mre] ....



So the debug output inside the function won't get triggered

I assume you're referring to the Write-Output call inside your Parse-CertTemplate function:

The call is made - it's just that it becomes part of the "return value" of the function, i.e. it writes to the success output stream and becomes part of the function's output, collected in the $templateData variable, which is why it produces no visible output.

Notably, a function's "return value" is not limited to what you pass to the return statement; return's primary purpose is flow control.


Do not use Write-Output for debugging purposes.

Use Write-Debug instead, and change the $DebugPreference preference variable from its default, 'SilentlyContinue' to 'Continue' to surface debug output.

In a pinch, you may use Write-Host, though you'll have to manually deactivate such calls when you're done debugging.




See this answer for more information.
